# filter and sort embed collection ( embedsMany relationship) mongodb db laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I want filter embed model with where clause, below query result is null list!

I want use laravel query builder and model [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and  it is different from other questions

```
 return Auth::user()->userTraffic()->first()->traffics()

                ->where('set_type', '=', 'manual')
                ->where('date_event', '<=', new  UTCDateTime( $endTimeStamp*1000))
                ->where('date_event', '>=', new  UTCDateTime( $startTimeStamp*1000))
            ;
///also test return all embed model and don't filter
Auth::user()->userTraffic()->first()->traffics()->
                whereRaw([ 'traffics.date_event' => array(
                    '$gte' => $start,
                    '$lte' => $end
                )])->get();

///also test return all embed model and don't filter

Auth::user()->userTraffic()->first()->traffics()
                    ->raw(function ($collection) use ($start, $end) {

                    return $collection->aggregate([
                       //[
                       //    '$unwind' => '$traffics'
                       //],
                        [
                            '$match' => [
                                'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                                'traffics.date_event' => array(
                                    '$gte' => $start,
                                    '$lt' => $end
                                )
                            ]
                        ],
                        array(
                            '$sort' => array("traffics.date_event" => -1),
                        ),
                    ]);
                });
```

timestamps to carbon:

> Carbon
>     date: 2018-11-06 00:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)
>
> Carbon 
>     date: 2018-11-06 23:00:00.0 Asia/Tehran (+03:30)

this duc is an object of user_traffic_collection and user's travels stored in traffics and now i want filter and sort this embed list and try some code but don't work . 
tanks for your attention .
my duc:

```
{  
"_id":ObjectId("5be002ac1f808f26b83af815"),
"user_id":1,
"update_at":   ISODate("2018-11-04T08:33:58   Z"),
"create_at":   ISODate("2018-11-04T08:33:58   Z"),
"traffics":[  
  {  
     "lat":55.56555555455,
     "lon":35.54598994564,
     "set_type":"manual",
     "traffic_type":0,
     "date_event":         ISODate("2018-12-09T05:56:47         Z"),
     "updated_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:56:47         Z"),
     "created_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:56:47         Z"),
     "_id":ObjectId("5be12d1fb3e94226f0006255")
  },
  {  
     "lat":55.56555555455,
     "lon":35.54598994564,
     "set_type":"manual",
     "traffic_type":1,
     "date_event":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:52         Z"),
     "updated_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:52         Z"),
     "created_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:52         Z"),
     "_id":ObjectId("5be12d9cb3e94226f0006256")
  },
  {  
     "lat":55.56555555455,
     "lon":35.54598994564,
     "set_type":"manual",
     "traffic_type":0,
     "date_event":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:53         Z"),
     "updated_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:53         Z"),
     "created_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:53         Z"),
     "_id":ObjectId("5be12d9db3e94226f0006257")
  },
  {  
     "lat":55.56555555455,
     "lon":35.54598994564,
     "set_type":"manual",
     "traffic_type":1,
     "date_event":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "updated_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "created_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "_id":ObjectId("5be12d9eb3e94226f0006258")
  },
  {  
     "lat":55.56555555455,
     "lon":35.54598994564,
     "set_type":"manual",
     "traffic_type":0,
     "date_event":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "updated_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "created_at":         ISODate("2018-11-06T05:58:54         Z"),
     "_id":ObjectId("5be12d9eb3e94226f0006259")
    }
]
}
```

***answer:*** finally below code work also return laravel model (Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model)

```
public function getLimitedTraffic($start, $end)
    {
        $result = Auth::user()->userTraffic()->raw(function ($collection) use ($start, $end) {

            return
                UserTraffic::hydrate($collection->aggregate([
                    [
                        '$match' => [
                            'user_id' => Auth::id(),

                        ]
                    ],

                    ['$project' =>
                        [
                            'traffics' => [
                                '$filter' => [
                                    'input' => '$traffics',
                                    'as' => 'traffic',
                                    'cond' => [
                                        '$and' => [
                                            ['$gte' => ['$$traffic.date_event', $start]],
                                            ['$lte' => ['$$traffic.date_event', $end]]

                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    ['$unwind'=>'$traffics'],
                    [
                        '$match' => [
                            'traffics.set_type' => 'manual',

                        ]
                    ],
                    ['$sort'=>[
                        'traffics.date_event'=>-1
                        ]
                    ],
                    [ '$group'=>
                        ['_id'=>'$_id',
                            'traffics'=>['$push'=>'$traffics']
                        ]
                    ]


                ])->toArray());
        });

        return $result->first()->traffics()->first();

    }
```

Comment: You're showing code without context of document samples you expect it to match. You need to provide people with a reproducible sample in order for them to help with diagnosing the problem. Remember that we are not sitting at your desk with access to everything you see. So include it all in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Neil Lunn added ducs and timestamps

Comment: Please add the "text" of the documents and not a picture. People cannot copy/paste and work with to verify based on a picture. You're asking people to waste time transcribing instead of helping you. To that end I suggest you put away the Compass GUI and open up a [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/)

Comment: @NeilLunn tanks for your suggestion i follow it.

Comment: Regarding your "edit", *"I want use laravel query builder ..'* - Then I'm not actually aware that it is capable of constructing such an aggregation expression using `$filter`. The advisable course here is to access the collection object from the model and use the `aggregate()` method from the driver just as demonstrated. Typically using `->raw()`. [First search result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50796783/2313887) I get shows an example of usage